# Can this integral be simplified?

Tags: calculus

Consider the integral $$
I(x, q) = \int_0^{\text{arctanh}(x)} q^{-w} \text{tanh}(w) dw
$$

Can this integral be simplified any further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variable $z=\tanh(w)$ yields: $\displaystyle
\color{red}{I(x,\mathrm e^{2r})=\int_0^x(1-z)^{r-1}(1+z)^{-r-1}z\,\mathrm dz}
$.

Comment: could you show how you got there?

Comment: Ok, got it now. Had that idea as well, but did not see it through as far as you did oO Thank you =)